# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f2d738e4137, pid=15464, tid=0x00007f2df6df9700

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, centos7, tesseract

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe8384b42be, pid=27917, tid=0x00007fe83b3fb700**strong text**
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_191-b12) (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.191-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libtesseract.so.4.0.0+0x2792be]  ELIST::add_sorted_and_find(int (*)(void const*, void const*), bool, ELIST_LINK*)+0x6e
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid27917.log
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

I checked limit.

> core file size    (blocks, -c) unlimited
>
> max locked memory (kbytes, -l) 64

I use tesseract in Centos7. This error occurs some time after the tesseract starts working. Then tomcat stopped. My program is not working. Why do you think?